# what should i replace localhost:3000 with in cpanel?

Tags: php, node.js, apache, cpanel

i have a website that contains both php and nodejs, part of the website works on localhost:8080, the nodejs part works on localhost:3000, i want to take the website online so i bought a domain name and a hosting plan that supports nodejs and installed node and npm and all the dependencies.. through cpanel i switched the links where there is localhost:8080 to domainname.com and it worked , i also switched the links where there is localhost:3000 to domainname.com.. but it's not working.. the website is working except for the nodejs part.. anyone have a suggestion ? did i do wrong by switching localhost:3000 to domainname.com? what should i do please in details...?

Comment: Did you try with domain_name.com:3000

Comment: yes i tried domainname:3000 but it didnt work